# Can I re-submit the same version of my app in google play?

Tags: android, google-play

I have accidentally uploaded a wrong version of my app in google play. Its version is 1.0. Now I am trying to upload the updated apk file using the same version which is 1.0. Is it still possible?

I tried but I always got this error message:

> You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1.

I try to unpublish it but I think I still need to wait for few hours. Most of the time, how long would this take?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app stores, not programming.

Comment: You must update the version code in incremental mode or you can upload same application using another account of google play.

Comment: @Wooble My apologies, I know this is not much related on programming. I am just asking help from experts regarding the app submission.

Comment: Using another account to submit the same application is definitely not a good idea.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can still use the same version. What it's asking for is `versionCode`, which you can increment from 1 to 2 in your `AndroidManifest.xml` (look for something like `android:versionCode="1"`).

There's more information here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

> android:versionCode — An integer value that represents the version of the application code, relative to other versions.
>
> The value is an integer so that other applications can programmatically evaluate it, for example to check an upgrade or downgrade relationship. You can set the value to any integer you want, however you should make sure that each successive release of your application uses a greater value. The system does not enforce this behavior, but increasing the value with successive releases is normative.
>
> Typically, you would release the first version of your application with versionCode set to 1, then monotonically increase the value with each release, regardless whether the release constitutes a major or minor release. This means that the android:versionCode value does not necessarily have a strong resemblance to the application release version that is visible to the user (see android:versionName, below). Applications and publishing services should not display this version value to users.

Comment: In this case, my app version is still version 1.0, right?

Comment: Yup, you can keep your version at 1.0 still.

Answer (score 7):

Inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, there are two lines at the top one for `versionCode` and one for `versionName`.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

The one for `versionName` doesn't actually matter what is there, it is for mainly the developer and consumers to know which version the app is on. The `versionCode` is intended for the developer only, as it is the only number that matters. The `versionCode` must increment on every release to the Play Store. Generally, the `versionCode` is either a plain number that increments with every release, or has a specific style to it, such as `YYYYMMDD`, as this number will always increment with the passing days.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In this case, my app version is still version 1.0, right? I'll try this out. Thank you.

Comment: I'll mark Waynn Lue response as an answer since he is the first one to answer. Though both of you are correct. Thank you.